# How to get other index from the current index

Tags: javascript, dom

i'm a newbie on JavaScript, help me to fix the problem i got.
I have an array, i want to remove class list for other div which are not same with the current index. Please help

i tried to find the answer from other discussion, but i still don't get what i want.

Here's the code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", ()=> {
const sounds = document.querySelectorAll(".sound");
const pads = document.querySelectorAll(".pads div");
const visual = document.querySelector(".visual");

pads.forEach((pad, index) => {
    pad.addEventListener("click", function() {
        sounds[index].currentTime = 0;
        sounds[index].play();
        popUpNote();

        const ind = index + 1;
        //I Need to got the other index from the current index,
        //like if current index is 2, then i want to get 0,1,3,4,5
        //since i have 6 index inside
        pad.classList.add("active-pad"+ind);

        sounds[index].addEventListener("ended", function() {
            const noteChild = document.querySelector(".visual div");
            noteChild.remove();
            pad.classList.remove("active-pad"+ind);
        });
    });
});

const popUpNote = () => {
    const note = document.createElement("div");
    visual.appendChild(note);
    note.style.animation = 'beatOn 1.5s ease-in-out infinite both';
};
```

});

I want to got the other index from the current index, like if the current index is 2, then i want to get 0,1,3,4,5 since i have 6 index inside

Comment: It's a little bit unclear of what you are asking.. do you want to eliminate the current index and rely on the newly formed array which will contain the new index because of the elimination? Asking that because of the array which you posted..

Answer (score 0):

Through this , might you get your solution ,

In this JS script , you will not get the current index .

```
var arr = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6];

arr.forEach(function(valuw , index){
    console.log(valuw , index);
   for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++){
    if( i != index){ 
    console.log("index at " , index , "itereator ===>" , i+1);
 }
}
});
```

Comment: You might want to check out `Array.prototype.filter()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.filter()` to find the other indexes:

```js
const idxs = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

const cur = 4

const res = idxs.filter(idx => idx !== cur)

console.log(res)
```